# Copiar e colar string sem máscara

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou utilizando um `MaskedTextBox` que contém uma máscara de CNPJ (`00.000.000/0000-00`).

Mas gostaria que quando eu copiasse essa string ela viesse para a área de transferência sem a máscara, para remover a máscara estou fazendo isso:

```
maskedTextBox1.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
//área de transferência = maskedTextBox1.Text; (???)
```

Porém não sei qual evento e a quem devo atribuir o valor sem formatação, para assim copiar (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) a string sem máscara para a área de transferência.

Comment: Você pode manipular com o `KeyDown` em cima do controle da `MaskedTextBox`.

Comment: @CypherPotato hmm verdade, mas a quem eu vou atribuir o valor sem máscara?

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(maskedTextBox1.Text)` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só atribuir `MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals` à propriedade `CutCopyMaskFormat`.

> [**MaskedTextBox.CutCopyMaskFormat**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.cutcopymaskformat?view=netframework-4.8)
>
> Obtém ou define um valor que determina  se os literais e os caracteres de prompt são copiados para a área de
> transferência.
>
> **[MaskedFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskformat?view=netframework-4.8)**
>
> Retorne apenas o texto inserido pelo usuário.

Comment: Até removi minha resposta pois essa é resposta correta. É simples e mais eficiente que interceptar os eventos de teclado.